# BJT Rpi Influence

Tags: amplifier, bjt, npn, gain

This question was already asked (by me) and I'm gonna ask it again(because the influence of Rπ wasn't explained good enough), but this time it is going to be interpreted the other way than last time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frrOJO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Measured overall voltage gain equals 60.

Calculated voltage gain with Rπ included equals 69. ->Ro = Rc || (R3||R4||Rπ) & Av = Ro * gm

Calculated voltage gain with Rπ excluded equals 193. ->Ro = Rc || (R3||R4) & Av = Ro * gm

So I'm asking again, why should Rπ even be neglected, since it has such important role when designing an amplifier (referring to its gain)?

Comment: You might want to update your question and explain what this Rn is. I do not see an Rn in the schematic for example.

Comment: My rough calculation of the voltage gain of the 1st stage: R1, R2 make 2 V at base Q1. Assuming Vbe = 0.7 then Ie = Ic = 4.3mA. If beta is 200 then Ib = 22 uA. Current through R1 is about 118 uA so I can neglect Ib. Ic = 4.3 mA so gm = 40*Ic = 172 mA/V. Since load at collector is mainly Rc gain is: Rc * gm = 260. Stage 2 is an common collector so it should have a gain of around 1x however is has a load of 4 ohms which is **too low**, it is a **very poorly dimensioned** circuit so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie R_pi is differential base-emitter resistance

Comment: Then I agree with Dan's answer. In general you want to dimension a CE stage such that Rn does not matter (much) or it does matter and the gain becomes unpredictable. You have the latter. You simply have a **poorly designed circuit** and yet you expect predictable results from it. Stop expecting more than your circuit can deliver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing Rπ is what I know as Rre (Intrinsic emitter resistance).

The gain is actually going to be highly variable as the first stage has no emitter degeneration at AC, so gain is actually highly dependent on Rre which is poorly controlled.

The second stage is just horrible as the load impedance (4 ohms) is so low that not only will the bias network fail to supply sufficient current, but the load on the first stage collector is strongly dependent on the beta of the second stage and that is a poorly controlled thing, Rre just adds insult to injury.

Half of transistor design is avoiding the effects of poorly controlled parameters (For example if you split that emitter resistor in the first stage in two and joined the cap Ce to the junction then ignoring the load from the second stage gain would be ~10 and the impact of Rre much less significant).

Comment: Not Rre but Rpi or differential base-emitter resistance.

Comment: Does this change anything?

Comment: The last sentence you wrote - splitting one transistor in two does decrease the voltage gain. So what is the advantage of this splitting?

Comment: Oh now it's called Rpi ? Geez, be clear what you mean. Learn to draw a small signal diagram and find out if it matters. We can say yes/no but that doesn't teach you anything, it might not matter in this circuit but it might matter in another circuit.

Comment: No I meant splitting Re and connecting Ce to the junction such that there is a non decoupled 150 ohms in series with a decoupled 150 ohms, 300 ohms then sets the DC operating point while the non decoupled emitter degeneration in combination with the collector load sets the stage gain.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean 150 ohms AC shorted, in series with 150 ohms non AC shorted. Then voltage gain would roughly be 1.5 k / 150 = 10. A lot less gain but you get a lot more **predictable gain** instead. Removed my comment as I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: *<<first stage has no emitter degeneration at AC, so gain is actually highly dependent on Rre>>* if you mean voltage gain and Rre=rpi this is not true.

Comment: Rre, the intrinsic emitter resistance, I am afraid semiconductor physics was a lot of years ago and I may have made an incorrect assumption that this was Rpi?

Comment: Rre is the small signal emitter series resistance. Rpi is also a small signal equivalent, Rpi = beta/gm and sits between base and emitter. I've never heard of OP's Rn, I guess he means Rpi and misread pi for an n. Saw that the question was updated, indeed it's Rpi.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am afraid OP actually wrote Rπ with right pi, it's just rendered here with rather poor font if outside MathJax

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie If I ever write down question like this I will refer to it as differential base-emitter resistance, so there won't be any misunderstood about its meaning.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Adding resistor before shorting AC to ground - I saw that somewhere, but I don't see the point of it, only that Av gets decreased, but how on earth is then Av more predictable I cannot really imagine. Can you explain it shortly?

Comment: See this lecture, sheet 37: https://www.utdallas.edu/~torlak/courses/ee3311/lectures/ch05updated.pdf It show the small signal equivalent circuit with an Re in place. Now consider the situation that Re = 0 ohm. When Re = 0, gm has a "hard" 1 to 1 relation with Av. If gm varies, Av follow it. gm in turn follows Ic directly and Ic varies over temperature, Vbe etc. Now assume Re has a larger value, for example Rc/10 then Av is much less dependent on gm. If Rc and Re are large enough, gm does almost nothing anymore. Av is then much less dependent on gm.

Comment: This behavior is the result of "local feedback", with a non-zero Re, when the input voltage increases, Ic increases and so does Ie, this increases the voltage across Re which in turn **works against** the input voltage rise. That is negative feedback, it resists the change caused by the change of Vin. That in turn causes only **part** of the input voltage change to occur across Vbe. That means less change in Ic and thus less gain.

Comment: Usually a well defined gain is one hell of a lot more important then  as much gain as possible, especially if that as much as possible varies all over the shop with temperature and device variations. Also the feedback lowers distortion (But makes the distortion spectra more complex). It is somewhat rare to see a single transistor linear amplifier in a real low frequency application that does not have emitter degeneration or some other form of feedback.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am very satisfied with your good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a DC blocking capacitor between speaker and emitter of Q2. Otherwise the biasing resistors are useless for predicting the operating point.

Comment: I know. But as the thing concerns of r_pi, what do you think about it?

Comment: The stage2 Rin will be 4 ohms * Beta. The Q2 will be overheating, with the DC path through the speaker. Current into collector Q2 will be 0.1 Amp. Power will be 1.5 watts.